# Is an inclusion always an homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Is the inclusion always an homeomorphism?
If not, which conditions must we have for such an assertion to be true?

What's the relationship between the image of the inclusion having the subspace topology, and the inclusion being a homeomorphism?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean homeomorphism onto its image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An **inclusion map** is any function $j:A\to B$, where $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $j(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$.  (Note that $A$ and $B$ need not have any particular structure in this case.)

A **homeomorphism** is any map $u:A\to B$, where $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces, $u$ is bijective, and both $u$ and $u^{-1}$ are continuous.

The only kind of map which is both an inclusion and a homeomorphism, therefore, is the identity map from a topological space onto itself.

EDIT:  However, it is worth noting that every inclusion map $f:A\to B$, where $B$ is a topological space and $A$ is a subspace (endowed with the subspace topology) is a homeomorphism when viewed as a map $f:A\to f(A)$ (where $f(A)$ is also endowed with the subspace topology).

EDIT #2:  Also, in the context of topological spaces, if $C$ and $B$ are topological spaces, $A$ is a subspace of $B$ (endowed with the subspace topology), and $u:C\to A$ is homeomorphism, then we may "abuse notation" and write that $u$ is an inclusion map when viewed as a function from $C$ into $B$.

Comment: One needs that the subset has the subspace topology.

Comment: @mfl You mean for an inclusion map?  Actually, you can have an inclusion between sets with no topological structure at all.

Comment: Yes. Your definition of inclusion map is between sets.

Comment: Ben,Thanks for your answer. I'm interested in your first Edit. How do you prove that? I know that the inclusion is continuous. But how do you prove that the inverse is also continuous?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. It's pretty much by definition.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. to elaborate, take an open $U$ in $A$.  We want to show that $f(U)$ is open in $f(A)$.  Since $f$ is the inclusion map, $f(A)=A$ and $f(U)=U$. QED.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the last comment. One last doubt, and I'll accept your answer. In your 2nd edit, you state that there's an abuse of notation... Where is it? because u from $C$ into $B$ would be a composition of the original $u$ with the inclusion from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. lol sure thing.  I guess you could put it this way.  If  $A$ and $C$ are homeomorphic, any map from $A$ into $B$ preserves precisely as much topological structure from any corresponding map from $C$ into $B$.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the extra clarifications in the comments ;)